# fromEvent(document,"storage") not working in Angular service

Tags: angular, typescript, events, rxjs, local-storage

We are storing the jwt-token in the localstorage, so I would love to get the event on the localstorage (change-event), so I can react to changes to the storage. For that reason I designed an RxJS Observable pipeline. The `isLoggedInSubject` is then subscribed from the Angular components.

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  private isLoggedInSubject: Observable<boolean> = null;
  private refreshTokenLogginStatus: BehaviorSubject<number> =
    new BehaviorSubject(0);
 
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private globals: Globals,
    private router: Router
  ) {
    this.isLoggedInSubject = combineLatest([
      this.refreshTokenLogginStatus,
      fromEvent(window, "storage"),
    ]).pipe(
      tap((v) => {
        console.log("isLoggedInSubject is triggered");
      }),
      map((v) => this.isLoggedIn()),
      distinctUntilChanged((prev, cur) => prev === cur)
    );
  }
```

As you can see the `refreshTokenLogginStatus` is a BehaviorSubject which is set on different method with a new random number. If I remove the  `fromEvent(window, "storage")` from the combineLatest everything works fine, that means the pipe runs through. If I add `fromEvent(window, "storage")` to the combineLatest() the whole pipe never runs (the console.log() never outputs the string). Is the problem the angular service? What confuse me really is, that if the `refreshTokenLogginStatus` is set with a new value the pipe also does not run through. As I understood it, the combineLatest() should now be performed anyway, because an observable of the two has changed. This is the difference between combineLatest() and zip().

PS: I also tried this [version](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h7iuws?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts). Here I made an method which sets the refreshtoken, but the method was never called.

PPS: I also tried to get an error on subscribe(), but nothing was fired.

Comment: [`window.onstorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event) fires only if the storage was changed in another document (other tab, other window) -- could this be the reason of your troubles?

Comment: I don't think so. It is one thing if the event is not fired. But in my case the whole pipe seems not working. Even if the BehaviourSubject changes, which should execute the pipe for that (combineLatest()), the pipe is not executed.

Comment: As you say before the `combineLatest()` operator fires when one of the `Observables` on it fires, but each observable should fire at least ones in order the `combineLatest()` emits. So if one of them never emits, the `combineLatest()` dont emits.

Comment: I guess that with the @alx comment, and my clarification you have an answer for this. If that is not the case, please notify us in order to provide you a more complete answer and maybe suggest you a workaround in your logic.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, your observable isn't firing because the `fromEvent()` never emits.  One way to solve this is to provide a default value using [`startWith`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/startwith):

```js
this.isLoggedInSubject = combineLatest([
    this.refreshTokenLogginStatus,
    fromEvent(window, "storage").pipe(startWith(localStorage.getItem('token')))
]).pipe(...);
```

---

Maybe it's good enough to determine `isLoggedIn` by presense of the token, in which case you could do something like:

```js
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class AuthService {

  private token$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>(localStorage.getItem('token'));

  private externalTokenChange$ = fromEvent<StorageEvent>(window, 'storage').pipe(
    filter(event => event.key === 'token'),
    map(event => event.newValue),
  );

  isLoggedIn$ = merge(this.token$, this.externalTokenChange$).pipe(
    map(token => !!token),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
  );

  setToken(token: string) {
    this.token$.next(token);
    localStorage.setItem('token', token);
  }

}
```

Here's a fun little [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-73591110?file=src%2Fapp%2Fauth.service.ts) example.